# Filling a polygon with some colour

Tags: matlab, draw, polygon, fill, polygons

I have the following that draws a polygon:

```
nVal = 33;
x = 164.8 + rand(nVal,1).*(354.6-164.8);
y = 66.3 + rand(nVal,1).*(222.3-66.3);
k = convhull(x,y);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b+')
```

If I want to fill out the shape, I think we can use [patch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html). But, it seems that I'm not using it correct, as I didn't get the whole shape filled.

I used the following:

```
 patch(x,y,'r')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fill`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fill.html):

```
fill(x(k),y(k),[.75 .75 .75]) %// light gray. Or change color as desired
```

If you want the original points to be seen, you have to plot them *after* `fill`:

```
fill(x(k),y(k),[.75 .75 .75])
hold on
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b+')
```

[image]